# Check if value exists in the list

Tags: python

Let’s say I have `123-0-1` and I want to check if this value exists inside the list. Below is the list that I have:

```
 df = [
       {'mpls': '123-0-1', 'source': '192.168.10.10', 'destination' : '12.168.100.10'}, 
       {'mpls': '123-0-1', 'source': '192.168.10.15', 'destination': '10.12.129.200'}
      ]
```

In SQL I would use:

```
select mpls, source from df where source = 192.168.10.10
```

From the list, I would like extract mpls `123-0-1` from the source `192.168.10.10` such that I can get the correct destination `12.168.100.10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df` is not a dataframe. It is a list of dictionaries.

As such, your only option is a loop and an `if` condition:

```
for connection in df:
    if connection['source'] == '192.168.10.10':
        print(connection['mpls'])
        print(connection['destination'])
        # do whatever with connection. Can also break if it is guaranteed to be unique.
```

However, if `df` *is* a dataframe, you can use pandas indexing syntax:

```
relevant_rows = df[df['source'] == '192.168.10.10']
```

`relevant_rows` will then be a new dataframe whose rows are those where `source` equals `'192.168.10.10'`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
       {'mpls': '123-0-1', 'source': '192.168.10.10', 'destination' : '12.168.100.10'},
       {'mpls': '123-0-1', 'source': '192.168.10.15', 'destination': '10.12.129.200'}
      ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

#         destination     mpls         source
#     0  12.168.100.10  123-0-1  192.168.10.10
#     1  10.12.129.200  123-0-1  192.168.10.15

relevant_rows = df[df['source'] == '192.168.10.10']

print(relevant_rows)

#         destination     mpls         source
#    0  12.168.100.10  123-0-1  192.168.10.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a dataframe of it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df[df['source'] == '192.168.10.10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using list comprehension, as you are working with lists:

```
[(x['mpls'], x['destination']) for x in df if x['source'] == '192.168.10.10']
```

It returns a tuple with `mpls` and `destination` based on `source`:

```
[('123-0-1', '12.168.100.10')]
```

Comment: ohh great! with this, I am able to list out all the mpls and destination that I need. Thanks for sharing !!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are just fine; just wanted to show how `next` could also be used:

```
df = [{'mpls': '123-0-1', 'source': '192.168.10.10', 'destination' : '12.168.100.10'}, {'mpls': '123-0-1', 'source': '192.168.10.15', 'destination': '10.12.129.200'}]

try:
  target = next(x for x in df if x['source'] == '192.168.10.10')
except StopIteration:
  print('Value not found!')
else:
  print(target['mpls'])         # -> 123-0-1
  print(target['destination'])  # -> 12.168.100.10
```

---

Note that this returns **only the first** `dictionary` that meets the criteria. based on your `SQL` statement, it seems that you want to get them **all**.

Comment: yes, i would like to get them all. Thanks for sharing !

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `filter` function to get filtered data from the list.

`filtered_list = filter((lambda x: x['source'] == '192.168.10.10'), df)`